# Why can't InstallUtil.exe find the manifest file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, installutil

I am trying to create a Windows service following this tutorial:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/create-and-install-windows-service-step-by-step-in-C-Sharp/

I am using batch code to install the service:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\User\Desktop\C#\TestService\bin\Debug
set DOTNET=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNET%
installutil.exe /i TestService.exe
net start TestService
pause
net stop TestService
installutil.exe /u TestService.exe
```

When I run this file, I get the following error:

Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\User\Desktop\C#\TestService\bin\Debug\TestService.exe' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest..
The service name is invalid.

It says the module was expected to contain a manifest, but there is a manifest file in the directory.
I've tried rebuilding but it doesn't change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the DOTNET path to
`%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`
and made sure to run as administrator every time. This seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. Found that rather than installing with the "setup.exe" file, installing from the "Application Files" folder with a "ApplicationName.exe.deploy" and having a *.exe.manifest file present in the directory allowed for the service to be installed.